# Delete string arrays that don't contain the values in either cells I1 J1 K1

Tags: vba, excel

I have string arrays in AC23-AC130 in the format of 2,5,8 and 7,8,8.

I am looking for code to set the data that must be checked against I1:K1, if that value doesn't have 1 match all the string arrays that don't match I1 J1 K1 must be deleted.

I tried the code at the button, but it doesn't run through.

so normal numbers in I1 J1 K1 must be checked against range of strings.
For example, if I1 J1 K1 is 8 7 7 then all the strings that don't contain a 8 7 7 must be deleted. Example: 2,4,1 don't contain a 8 7 7 so it must be deleted. 4,5,8 contains a 8 so it shouldn't be deleted.

```
Sub Tester()

Dim sKeep As String, x As Long
Dim rngSearch As Range, c As Range

    'J1:K1 has values to keep and checked against arrays Ac23-ac130
    sKeep = Chr(0) & Join(Application.Transpose(Range("j1:k1").Value), _
                                Chr(0)) & Chr(0)

    Set rngSearch = Range("AC23:AC130")

    For x = rngSearch.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set c = rngSearch.Cells(x)
        If InStr(sKeep, Chr(0) & c.Value & Chr(0)) = 0 Then
            c.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: I want to make sure I understand, you want to check for each cell in column AC ("AC23:AC130"), that it's contents doesn't equal for at least one of the cells "I1:K1" then delete that cell. If one of the numeric values inside it match to one of the cells, then don't delete it, right ? Each cell in Column AC has a few numbers inside it ? with a `,` as a delimiter ?

Comment: have you tested te code in my answer below ? any feedback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below loops through all cells in Column AC ("AC23:AC130"), and for each cell it's using the `Split` to put the values in an array.

Afterwards, it check for every cell in Range("I1:K1") and uses the `Application.Match` to see if the array exists in one of the cells. If it does, then it doesn't delete it, if there is no match then it deletes the current cell.

**Code**

```
Sub Tester()

Dim sKeep As String, x As Long
Dim rngSearch As Range, c As Range
Dim CelArr As Variant, DelFlag As Boolean

Set rngSearch = Range("AC23:AC130")

For x = rngSearch.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

    CelArr = Split(rngSearch.Item(x), ",") '<-- convert values in column AC to array
    DelFlag = True '<-- init delete flag

    If Len(Join(CelArr)) > 0 Then '<-- check if array (current cell) is empty
        For Each c In Range("I1:K1").Cells
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(CStr(c.Value), CelArr, 0)) Then '<-- if there is at least 1 match, don't delete the cell
                DelFlag = False '<-- don't delete current cell with a match
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    End If

    If DelFlag Then rngSearch.Item(x).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Works flawlessly Thank you very much Shai much appreciated Sir...Great coding!!!!!

Comment: @Ricklou  you're welcome, please mark as answer (click the **V** next to my answer )

Comment: @Ricklou why did you take off the **V** of my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

you could use `AutoFilter()` to filter cells not complying "I1" and "J1" values and then loop through such filtered cells and gather (with `Union()`) the ones that doesn't comply with "K1")

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim delRng As Range, c As Range

    With Range("AC22:AC130")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*" & Range("I1").Value & "*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>*" & Range("J1").Value & "*" '<--| filter cells that don't match the first two criteria
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
            Set delRng = .Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 1) '<--| set 'delRng' to a "dummy" cell not to have to check it against 'Nothing' at every iteration of subsequent loop 
            For Each c In .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                If InStr(c.Value, Range("k1").Value) = 0 Then Set delRng = Union(c, delRng) '<--| add to 'delRng' cells that don't match the "last" criteria neither
            Next
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
            Set delRng = Intersect(delRng, .Cells) '<--| get rid of the "dummy" 'delRng' cell
            If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp '<--| if any cell to be deleted found then delete t hem in one shot
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```